# Facebook Prompt automatically disappearing on iOS 7

Tags: facebook, ios7

I am working with Share kit for Facebook sharing. and using action sheet to open a Facebook popup. Its working fine on iOS 6 or previous version.

But in iOS 7 its automatically disappeared on action sheet button click.

Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Find the method -(void)showWebView in FBDialog.m (around line 410).

Replace this code

```
if (!window) {  
    window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];   
}
```

With this

```
if (window.windowLevel != UIWindowLevelNormal) {
    for(window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        if (window.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal)
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tested it on iOS7 and iOS6, it works.

Have a nice day :)